# Using datepicker for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, datepicker

I'm writing a chrome extension that uses datepicker, and I'm running into a lot of issues. The calendar opens, but it's not clickable--I can't actually select a date. I've been looking around and I haven't found much about datepicker for chrome extensions online, so I'm just wondering if anyone has had similar issues?

I'm using jquery 1.9.1 and bootstrap#~3.2.0

Here is my code to trigger the datepicker:

```
 j(document).on('click', '.datepicker-input', function(){
  j(this).datepicker();
});
```

and

```
<input class="datepicker-input" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

Comment: Hmm AFAIK jquery should work fine in both chrome and firefox extensions. However, i'm not sure about how bootstrap works from within extensions - have you tried doing the same in a fiddle to see if there's code unrelated to your extension that might be conflicting between the two frameworks, given your current implementation?

Comment: Paste the contents of your manifest file as well.